# Publishing Ionic wrapper for Cordova plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, appery.io

Is there a way to create Ionic wrapper for Cordova plugin other than publishing it to `awesome-cordova-plugins` repository like described at
https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md

I would like to store all needed files in the same repository as my Cordova plugin.

My question is how to create those files. For `awesome-cordova-plugins`
I run `npm run build` to get the following files in dist folder:

```
./ngx/index.js
./ngx/index.d.ts
./ngx/index.metadata.json
./index.js
./index.d.ts
```

When trying to build a main project with Cordova plugin I get an error:

```
[error] Error: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/zebra-printer" has missing dependencies:

@angular/core
@ionic-native/core
```

Cordova plugin repository can be found here:
https://github.com/a-services/cordova-zebra-printer

Answer (score 0):

**You have to first install**

> `npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core --save` //once per project - for details [click here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community) .

Comment: But this is Ionic5 project with many Cordova plugins that already uses `@ionic-native/core`
Do you think coexisting `@awesome-cordova-plugins/core` and `@ionic-native/core` in a same project is a good practice?